# Buy a roundtrip ticket for two people, but second person only travels on return - is that possible

Tags: air-travel, tickets, airlines, bookings

If I buy airline tickets for a roundtrip for two people, and the second person does not show up for the first part of the roundtrip, do airlines cancel the return ticket for that person, or can that person fly the return trip only?

Comment: The short answer is no. If any passenger no-shows on any segment of an itinerary, the airline will cancel all subsequent segments for that passenger.